# How to deny a called process to write to the inherited console window

Tags: c++, inheritance, process, console

I'm writing a program which can call multiple processes and keep track of them. Since this is a school project, I only need to call compiled code (.exe) that has simple tasks (array sorts, list sorts etc). The problem is that my `PARENT PROCESS` has an ascii console interface built with `moveCursor(x,y)` and if the `CHILD PROCESS` has an `std::cout` or `printf()` it writes over my `PARENT PROCESS` interface.

**QUESTION:** Whithout modifying the `CHILD PROCESSES` code to simply don't have screen prints how can i deny the inheritance of the `PARENT PROCESS` console window and block the `CHILD PROCESSES` to create a new console window?

I'm using `CreateProcess()` to start the processes.

I'm looking for a **WINDOWS** solution.

Here is my `Process` class which i use to manage my processes.

```
class Process
{
    private:
        STARTUPINFO startInfo;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
        CHAR pathToExe[EXTENDED_MAX_PATH];
        DWORD returnedValue;
    public:

    /** I don't know how to pass a LPCSTR parameter to the constructor so i simply use
        another function to construct the class */
    /** I also don't want a global string and to simply modify it before i declare my object */
    bool Create(LPCSTR pathToFile)
    {
        ZeroMemory(&startInfo,sizeof(startInfo));
        ZeroMemory(&processInfo,sizeof(processInfo));
        ZeroMemory(&pathToExe,sizeof(pathToExe));
        ZeroMemory(&returnedValue,sizeof(returnedValue));
        strcpy(pathToExe,pathToFile);
        bool hasProcessStarted = CreateProcess(pathToFile,NULL,NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,NULL,NULL,&startInfo,&processInfo);
        return hasProcessStarted;
    }

    bool IsRunning()
    {
        if (GetExitCodeProcess(processInfo.hProcess,&processInfo.dwProcessId))
            if (processInfo.dwProcessId == STILL_ACTIVE) return true;
        return false;
    }

    /** Kind of a destructor. I just made another function because its easier to manage all the data*/
    /** Also all the Process Class Objects are dynamically allocated so i just simply delete them after Kill() returns true*/
    bool Kill(bool skipIfRunning)
    {
        if (skipIfRunning == true && IsRunning()) return false;
        if (TerminateProcess(processInfo.hProcess,0))
        {
            ZeroMemory(&startInfo,sizeof(startInfo));
            ZeroMemory(&processInfo,sizeof(processInfo));
            ZeroMemory(&pathToExe,sizeof(pathToExe));
            ZeroMemory(&returnedValue,sizeof(returnedValue));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    DWORD GetProcessReturnedValue()
    {
        return processInfo.dwProcessId;
    }

};
```

Comment: You might be looking for `DETACHED_PROCESS` flag.

Comment: When you 'call' the "compiled code (.exe)", can you redirect the std::cout  of the called exe?  In Linux, this is expressed using '>' to identify the device to display std::cout of the 'spawned .exe'.  For example:  "ls > /dev/pts/0" redirects the output of 'ls' command to an open terminal (in a different window), thus protecting your parent's console window.  The device (/dev/pts/0) is found simply using command tty.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i have tried `DETACHED_PROCESS` alone and with other tags, still it does the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of the [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) is the "command line".

Use it (instead of NULL) and [redirect](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout) otputs to "null"

```
mycommandline = fullFilePath + " 1>nul 2>nul" 
CreateProcess(pathToFile, mycommandline , ...)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what u mean by that "1>nul 2>nul". I suppose by that + you mean to concatenate the "1>nul 2>nul" to the path of the .exe ?

Comment: Yes, with a blank in between. It's like you call the app and pass arguments. Read the "redirect" link. Open a command box and play with the samples, by typing yourself, then hit "enter" and see the results.

Comment: My bad, i was just running the wrong project and wondered why it wouldn't work.